# How to exclude subviews from animation?

Tags: iphone, subview

[image]I am developing an application in which i am creating small sub views in the same view.

What i want is when i change the value of alpha of the view, the value of alpha for sub view is also getting changed which i do not want.

How to implement the code for changing the value of the view not the small sub views created.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested already, you should not add YourSubVew as subview of YourMainView. 
Make both of your views a subview of an empty and transparent common subview (ContainerView) which has the same size and position that YourMainView currently has.

```
ContainerView -> YourMainView 
              -> YourSubView
```

Make sure to add YourMainView first as subview of ContainerView before you add YourSubView as subview of ContainterView. Otherwise YourMainView may overlap/hide YourSubView.

Doing so you can set both views' alpha independend from each other.

(Omar's answer is quite correct, but his "graphical visualisation" is misleading and it missed the point of the sequence of the subviews.)

Edit: 
What you have today is like this:

```
yourMainView.alpha = 1.0;
...
[yourMainView addSubView:yourSubView];
yourMainView.alpha = 0.1; //probably with animations etc.
```

What happens is, that yourSubView will "inherit" the alphaValue of its superview. 
ANd there is even more to that. Assuming that your subView has an alpha of 0.5, that would effectively become 0.05 when when its superview's alpha is set to 0.1.

Change that code to:

```
containerView = [[UIView alloc] init]; //you may choose a different init method
//If you use initWithFrame then use the frame of yourMainView. 
//However, make sure that ContainterView is of the same size as yourMainView and has the same position. 
[containerView addSubView:yourMainView];
yourMainView.alpha = 1.0;
```

...
    [containerView addSubView:yourSubView]; //add it to the container too!
    yourMainView.alpha = 0.1; //this will now effect the MainView only.

That is basically all the trick. Views can perfectly well overlap each other without being subviews. Make them subviews only then when they really are subveiws, when they are moved togehter, appear and disappear together, etc.

Comment: I agree to your point but what i am doing is , i am clicking a button which will give me a small view dynamically . what i want is the background view should have less alpha and the small view created has 1 as alpha value. As you can see the white view..it's alpha value is also changing..I don't want that

Comment: Yes. Just introduce a new view that is behind both of your current views. Do not create a chain of subviews but a "fork", where your current background view and your new subview are subviews of the newly introduced common background view. (ContainerView) Then you can change the alpha of your YourMainView and set it to 0 or 0.1 or so and the alpha of YourSubView may still be 1 or 0.5 or so. I'll try to extend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that, the alpha is inheritate, so what you have to do is to change the view structure from

YourMainView -> Your SubView

To

ContainerView ->YourMainView
              -> Your SubView

So now YourMain View the one that you want to apply the animation, is not the paret view of your current subView, the both views are sibilings, also ContainerView will have a clear background, so it wont affect it will just contain both the views

Comment: What if he wants to change the alpha values of the subviews only? is that possible?

Comment: Yes, why not, he could change it, if he wants to do that, then no reason to change the structure